# Firestore query by server timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to filter a Firestore query using the server's timestamp? When trying to perform a query such as:

```
firebase.app.firestore()
  .collection('posts')
  .where('timestamp', '<=', firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp())
```

The following error is thrown.

```
FirebaseError: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. FieldValue.serverTimestamp() can only be used with update() and set()
```

I know that I can use `new Date()` instead of `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, but it would be nice if there was a way to query using the trusted server timestamp. My use case is a collection of discount codes with expiry dates, where the expiry dates are saved as Firestore timestamps. If a user changes their system time this query can potentially return invalid (expired) results if I rely on a client-side date for filtering. I'm using Firebase functions to actually process the discount (where it is easy to validate the expiry using the server timestamp), so users with incorrect system times would still not be able to actually use the discount code. Nonetheless it would be nice to  guarantee the time in such a query to never show an expired code in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is a *flag*, not a real value - it instructs FireeStore to use the current server time as a value *during a write operation*.  It is NOT a true "value" that you can use as a substitute for "now".

What you are thinking of (and want to use) is `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()`, (sp?) https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp , which uses Epoch time (compensating for timezone).  Changing their local clock will NOT defeat this - as you *may* have noticed elsewhere, most browsers and services (including Firestore) need tot local clock to be fairly accurate to maintain operations.  If your user/hacker sufficiently hacks their local clock to try to get around your rules, their Firestore service won't be working anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the `Timestamp.now()` method also just uses the local Date: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/50195991a514d16ee40d08fe32d308111f7917e3/packages/firestore/src/lite/timestamp.ts#L45. Your point about Firestore not working if the time is too off is valid though. I'm going to accept this as the answer because it contains some good info, but I think the only solution here is to get the server involved (via functions or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about a problem similar to yours.

Late reply, but I'll write a solution in hopes that it will help

As you know, "firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()" cannot be used for querying, and it is very uncertain to query with the device's built-in Timestamp. (e.g. things like currentTimestamp(), Date() )

In this case, the solution may be to use the Security Rule in Firestore.

In my case, I used that method to restrict users.

The "suspesnsions_user" collection is used to limit membership due to fraudulent use of users. (User's membership must be suspended before releasedTimestamp.)

```
match /suspensions_user/{userId} {
    allow read : if request.auth.uid == userId && resource.data.releasedTimestamp > request.time
}
```

If the Security Rule is used as follows, **if the user can access the document located in "suspensions_user/{userId}" through the relevant Security Rule, it can be determined that he is in the status of loss of membership.**

Conversely, **if the user cannot access the document for reasons such as permission denied , it can be determined that he has normal membership.**

As you said in the question, accurate validation is possible if you apply the corresponding Security Rule to a document such as "/coupons/{id}" to validate access to coupons.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase rule shown below forces the system time to be almost accurate.

```
// expired_at: coupon expiration timestamp
// request.time: firestore server time
// duration.time(0, 0, 5, 0): consideration for network time
resource.data.expired_at >= request.time - duration.time(0, 0, 5, 0)
```

Firestore queries must guarantee the above rule, so `new Date()` must be in the future than 5 seconds before server time.
Otherwise, this query will fail.

```
where("expired_at", ">=", new Date())
```

[image]

This method is not perfect, but it meets the criteria I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I do to keep my date comparisons accurate:

```
let timestamp = new Date().toISOString();
// "2021-03-01T11:10:51.392Z"
```

If you do this in your Firebase Function (or in the client), you'll always get *UTC time*, in ISO format (ISO 8601).

This is great because you can do simple [String comparisons of ISO 8601](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/iso-time.html) date strings.

Comment: I don't see how using UTC and ISO-8601 has any bearing on the local system clock being inaccurate.